# resolve the ambiguity for the dimensional model for one to many(fact to dimension) ratio

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact

I have a question regarding facts and dimensions.

suppose I have come across a fact table fact_trips - composed of columns like
trip_id ,
driver_id,
vehicle_id,
date ( in the int form - 'YYYYMMDD') ,
timestamp (in milliseconds - bigint ),
miles,
time_of_trip

[image]

I have another dim_alerts - composed of columns like
trip_id,
Alert_id,
Alert_type,
Number_of_alerts_per_type_per_trip_id,
total_alerts_per_trip_id

[image]

important thing to note is that, there is one-to-many mapping between fact and dimension over here. So, a trip_id - 1 might have multiple entries in the dim_alerts table

How do I relate them? Do I use a surrogate key or what? cause the key here is that if i include alert_id in the fact table, then for every trip_id, there will multiple alert_id's , which will add more records in the fact.

The DWH necessarily gauzes the action the user takes on his phone_app
while he is driving his car. The act of driving the car is called as a trip. A single trip can consists of multiple alerts.

[image]

Comment: Please can you explain what alerts are, how/when they are created, etc.? They seem to be measures and so should be in a fact table, not a dimension

Comment: @NickW , please refer the problem, I have added some more explanation.

Comment: Alerts are facts so need to be in their own fact table, not a dimension

Comment: @NickW , thanks for this. was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

TripAlerts is a fact, not a dimension.  So you have a table: FactTripAlert with primary key (TripId,AlertId).